# How do i utilize IF functions (or others) in order to create a simple username/password in google sheets?

Tags: windows, formulas, google-sheets

On cell A3, there is a username input (i.e max or dave), on cell B3, there is a pin input (i.e 1234 if its max, or 8640 if its dave), how would you go about creating a formula in order to satisfy these requirements? That is, if you put 1234 in cell B3, but Dave in cell A3, it would show as "invalid", otherwise it would show as "Verified"?

So far, I have created an IF(AND ...) statement that just accomplishes one pair (i.e Dave with 8640 only), how can i add MULTIPLE people and pin numbers, with the results of "verified" or "invalid" to be output into one cell (C3)?

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

- Username to test in A3
- Pin to test in B3
- Username list in A5:A
- Pin list in B5:B

```
=IFNA(IF(
   VLOOKUP(A3, A5:A, 2, 0)=B3,
   "verified", "invalid-A"), "invalid-B")
```

- invalid-A returned if pin doesn't match
- invalid-B returned if no username matched

Comment: Hello, Thank you for answering. This makes alot of sense! I like the idea of making a list of all users/pins on most probably a seperate sheet and utilize vlookup! Makes stuff much easier, thank you

Comment: My pleasure!  Consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer if it helped. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)